Different transitive assembly resolution for dynamically loaded assemblies under .NET and .NET Framework
I have observed a rather curious difference in the CLR assembly loading behavior between .NET 7 and .NET Framework 4.6.1 targeted applications.
For the context, let me first explain the architecture on which I have observed the assembly loading differences. It is a kind of plugin system for applications, where basically we have a „reference“ console application referencing all the other netstandard2.0 libraries from the solution. Build of the „reference“ application publishes binaries to a folder specific for each of the platforms targeted (in our case they are net7.0 and net461). Other applications then use these folders to dynamically load assemblies as needed.
I have managed to create a  simple repro here mimicking the architecture as follows:

TestContracts is a netstandard2.0 project exposing the ITracer  interface.
TestLibrary is a netstandard2.0 project, it has dependency on TestContract, exposes a Tracer class implementing the ITracer interface and also has a dependency on  Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch NuGet package (which in turn, has transitive dependency on  System.Text.Json v8.0.5 NuGet package containing the System.Text.Json.dll assembly version 8.0.0.0).
TestReferenceApp is multitargeted to net7.0 and net461, it references TestContracts  and TestLibrary projects and the build publishes TestReferenceApp to PublishedAppNet70 and PublishedAppNet461 folders specific to the appropriate targets (uses the dotnet publish CLI after build – see TestReferenceApp.csproj).
TestApp is the entry point, it has dependency only on TestContracts, it loads the  TestLibrary assembly dynamically using Assembly.LoadFrom from the  TestReferenceApp\PublishedApp*  folder specific to a given .NET target and then creates an instance of the Tracer class casting it to the ITracer interface. When invoking the ITracer.Trace method, the .net7.0 build throws the following exception upon calling the ITracer.Trace method:
System.IO.FileLoadException
  HResult=0x80131621
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)
  Source=Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch
  StackTrace:
   at Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientSettingsBase`1..ctor(NodePool nodePool, IRequestInvoker requestInvoker, SourceSerializerFactory sourceSerializerFactory, IPropertyMappingProvider propertyMappingProvider)
   at Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientSettings..ctor(NodePool nodePool, IRequestInvoker requestInvoker, SourceSerializerFactory sourceSerializer, IPropertyMappingProvider propertyMappingProvider)
   at Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientSettings..ctor(NodePool nodePool, IRequestInvoker requestInvoker, SourceSerializerFactory sourceSerializer)
   at Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientSettings..ctor(NodePool nodePool)
   at Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClientSettings..ctor(Uri uri)
   at TestLibrary.Tracer.Trace(String message) in D:\_data\GithubRepos\PaloMraz\AssemblyDependencyLoadingApp\TestLibrary\Tracer.cs:line 12
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\_data\GithubRepos\PaloMraz\AssemblyDependencyLoadingApp\TestApp\Program.cs:line 21

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(string)
    System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(string)
    System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFromResolveHandler(object, System.ResolveEventArgs)
    System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.InvokeResolveEvent(System.ResolveEventHandler, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, string)

Inner Exception 1:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

The net461 build works like a charm.
Can anyone shed light on why the behavior is different?

well, is the correct version of system.text.json.dll present in the folder? I.e. is this a build error or runtime error. You can use something like ILSpy to inspect a dll to see what framework it targets.

It is a runtime error, the folder TestReferenceApp.PublishedAppNet70 contains the correct assembly (System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51) but the runtime refuses to load it from the folder for some mysterious reason...
